# How to download all submitted documents at once in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

All submissions to my form have uploaded documents. How can I download all of these documents at once?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not currently have the ability to download all of the uploaded files. However this is something that we do plan to work on in a future release. You can follow our progress on this over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/RBSfDsPl).